# How to call a function inside Controller-A from Controller-B in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

MY code is like this

```
Controller.JS
    angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers', []).controller('ReadOnlyController', function($scope, rateRequestService) {
    $scope.rateData = [];

    rateRequestService.getData().success(function(response) {
        $scope.rateData = response;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

         $scope.openModal();
    });
});

angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope, $modal, $log) {


    $scope.openModal = function(size) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: size,

        });
    };


});


App.JS

    angular.module('RateRequestApp', [
   'RateRequestApp.services',
   'RateRequestApp.controllers',
   'ui.bootstrap'
]);
```

As you can see I am trying to call a function `$scope.openModal();` inside another controller, And obviously it throws an error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

at line

```
   $scope.openModal();
```

Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since controllers are not injectable, I would not try.  Try leveraging shared services instead.

Comment: Well they may be injectable through the $controller service... but why would you do that? I would argue its not good design.

Comment: I don't completely understand your answer can you please elaborate more?

Comment: You cannot inject 'ReadOnlyController' into another controllers function. Angular does not allow that. There is a good reason, it was not designed to allow that.

Comment: Isn't there any other solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can inject a controller into another controller using angular controller service   $controller

```
angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers', []).controller('ReadOnlyController', ['$controller','$scope', function($scope, rateRequestService,$controller) {
    var modalDCtrl = $scope.$new();
    $controller('ModalDemoCtrl',{$scope : modalDCtrl });
    $scope.rateData = [];
    rateRequestService.getData().success(function(response) {
        $scope.rateData = response;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        modalDCtrl.openModal();
    });
}]);
```

However you also need to attach the method to the controller instance instead of $scope.

```
angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers').controller('ModalDemoCtrl',  function($scope, $modal, $log) {
    this.openModal = function(size) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: size,
        });
    };
});
```

Referencing : [How do I inject a controller into another controller in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417162/how-do-i-inject-a-controller-into-another-controller-in-angularjs)

Comment: Your code gives me an error
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ReadOnlyController' is not a function, got string

Comment: Edited. Perhaps because I forgot '[' for dependency injection. 
Basically use the same code setup you had but 
-inject $controller service into your 'ReadOnlyController'
- Define the other controller using 
  $controller('ModalDemoCtrl',{$scope : modalDCtrl });
- change "$scope" to "this" in 'ModalDemoCtrl'

Comment: Now this throws an error TypeError: undefined is not a function at line
modalDCtrl.openModal();

Comment: Try to create an isolated scope by passing true in the $new() method -  $new(true).

Answer (score 0):

Define your controllers inside the app and then inject them as required. You haven't mentioned the implementation of your model instance controller. So I assume you have forgotten to implement it.

```
angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers', []).controller('ReadOnlyController', function($scope, rateRequestService) { 
                // ReadOnlyController's logic
}));

angular.module('RateRequestApp.controllers').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope, $modal, $log) { 

/**
 *  This might be missing
 */
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modal) {
            // ModalInstanceController's logic
};

$scope.openModal = function(size) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            size: size,

        });
    };

}));



App.JS

    angular.module('RateRequestApp', [
   'RateRequestApp.services',
   'RateRequestApp.controllers',
   'ui.bootstrap'
]);
```

Hope above snippet would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

$controller will helpfull, try this link https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller you will get good idea.