# 'Unknown provider' error while retrieving lazy-loaded controller

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading, oclazyload

I want 'MyController2' to inherit 'MyController1', however, both controllers are lazyloaded using ocLazyLoad. According to *Jussi Kosune*n's answer to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15292441/2197555), I have made a function `registerDynamic()` to register the controllers, but it still reports the following error at the line with '$controller' in controller1.js:

**Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $elementProvider <- $element <- DataTableController**

My codes are like this.

First file `controller1.js`:

```
angular.module( 'myApp',[])
    .controller( 'MyController1', [ function($scope){
        // ...
    }]);
```

Second file `controller2.js`:

```
angular.module( 'myApp')
    .controller( 'MyController2', [ '$controller', '$scope',function($controller, $scope){
         $controller('MyController1', {$scope: $scope }); // here triggers error '[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider'
         // ...
    }]);
```

In the third File `lazy-load.js`, I lazyload the above two .js files:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp'),
queueLen = app._invokeQueue.length;
app.directive( 'LazyLoad', [ function( ){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
           src: '@',
        },
        link: function( scope, element, attr ){
            var registerDynamic = function() {
                // Register the controls/directives/services we just loaded
                var queue = syncreonApp._invokeQueue;
                for(var i=queueLen;i<queue.length;i++) {
                    var call = queue[i];
                    // call is in the form [providerName, providerFunc, providerArguments]
                    var provider = syncreonApp.providers[call[0]];
                    if(provider) {
                        // e.g. $controllerProvider.register("Ctrl", function() { ... })
                        $log.debug("Registering " + call[1] + " " + call[2][0] + " ...");
                        provider[call[1]].apply(provider, call[2]);
                    }
                }
                queueLen = i;
            },
            loadMultipleJs = function ( js_files ){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var js_file1 = js_files.shift(),
                    js_file2 = js_files.shift();

                 $ocLazyLoad.load( js_file1 )
                    .then ( function(){
                        registerDynamic();
                        $ocLazyLoad.load( js_file2 )
                            .then ( function(){
                                registerDynamic();
                                deferred.resolve();
                            }, function(){
                                deferred.reject();
                            });
                    }, function(){
                        deferred.reject();
                    });
           };
           jsonOfJsFilesToLoad = JSON.parse(scope.src);
           loadMultipleJs(jsonOfJsFilesToLoad );
       }
   };
}]);
```

---

**UPDATE**

[The official Angular documentation for 'Unknown Provider' error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$elementProvider%20%3C-%20$element%20%3C-%20DataTableController) says:

> Attempting to inject one controller into another will also throw an Unknown provider error:

Maybe we just cannot injector controller into anther even using $controller service?

Comment: Try to inject $controller service into second controller

Comment: @csharpfolk  Thanks for pointing out that. I forgot it when writing the question. I had it in original code. Question edited.

Comment: You can certainly instanitiate another controller inside a controller, see [use case for $controller service in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27868095/5535245). So look elsewhere for your problem. Where are you trying to inject `$element`? `$element` is not a service. It is a **local** supplied by `$compile`.

Comment: @georgeawg I don't think I have injected `$element` anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the error message out of context.

> Attempting to inject one controller into another will also throw an Unknown provider error:
>
> ```
> angular.module('myModule', [])
>    .controller('MyFirstController', function() { /* ... */ })
>    .controller('MySecondController', ['MyFirstController', function(MyFirstController) {
>      // This controller throws an unknown provider error because
>      // MyFirstController cannot be injected.
>    }]);
> ```

That is not the way you are instantiating controllers.

It specifically says:

> **Use the $controller service** if you want to instantiate controllers yourself.

Which is the way you **are** instantiating your controllers.

Look for your problem elsewhere.

Your error message:

> Unknown provider: $elementProvider <- $element <- DataTableController

The way I read this is that in your `DataTableController`, you are trying to inject `$element`. `$element` is not a service is a **local**. To inject `$element` as a **local** with the `$controller` service:

```
$controller('DataTableController', {$scope: $scope, $element: value });
```

Comment: `$element` as a local in controllers injected by `$compile` is documented in [AngularJS $compile API References -- controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-). `$element` **not a local** in controllers injected by `ngRoute` is documented in [AngularJS ngRoute $route API Reference -- current](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#current). What `DataTableController` is doing with `$element` is something you should investigate.

Comment: You are correct. I did use $element in `DataTableController`. It is my error.Thank you very much for the excellent analytic answer.