# How to call a controller from another file in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, http-post

Let's say I have the following files:

**JS1 file:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrlOfJs1', function ($scope, $http) {
   $http.post("url", data).success(function(data, status) {
      $scope.hello = data;
   })
})
```

**JS2 file:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrlOfJs2', function ($scope, $http) {
   // $http.post("url", data).success(function(data, status) {
     // $scope.hello = data;
  // })
})
```

What I don't want is rewrite the same `code` twice. Then I want to call that function in my JS1 file, in the JS2 file. Is it possible?

**PS:** It's only an example, my code has much more lines than it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use services: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

```
app.factory('commonFeatures', function($http) {
    return {
        setHelloMsg: function(scope) {
           $http.post("url", data).success(function(data, status) {
               scope.hello = data;
           })
        }
    };
});

app.controller('myCtrlOfJs1', function ($scope, commonFeatures) {
    commonFeatures.setHelloMsg($scope);
});
```

**edit**:
As a response to your comment:

Well, it **can** be located nearly everywhere. Have a look at https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#single-responsibility. There are more style guides, but I personally follow this one and it just makes sense.

Your view doesn't have to change at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's interesting, but I have some doubts: where should be located this factory? In which file? 1 or 2? And how will you works the "calling" in view? For ex: <div ng-controller="myCtrlOfJs1">? And the other controller?

Comment: I still can't make it work. Please see my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FueoGycorfiIXN0hxC6a?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to separate common functionality like this out into angular services: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

In this example it might look like this:

```
var andyModule = angular.module('anyModule', []);

andyModule.factory('helloDataService', function($http) {
    var helloDataService = {
        // returns a promise
        getHelloData = function() {
            return $http.post("url", data)
        }
    };
    return shinyNewServiceInstance;
});
```

And in your controller

```
app.controller('myCtrlOfJs1', function ($scope, $http, helloDataService) {
    helloDataService.getHelloData().success((data)=> {
        $scope.data = data;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would abstract this to a service. Services are particularly good spots for things like network calls.

By the way using `angular.module("app", modules)` syntax will *create* an app named app, so JS2 file will overwite the module from JS1. I doubt you intend this.

```
angular.module("app", []);

var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('myCtrlOfJs1', function ($scope, hello) {
  hello.post().then(data => scope.$hello = data);
});

var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('myCtrlOfJs2', function ($scope, hello) {
  hello.post().then(data => scope.$hello = data);
});

app.factory("hello", function ($http) {
  // set data somehow
  return {
      post() {
        return $http.post("url", data);
      },
  };
});
```

This still duplicates the `scope.$hello` code which may be what you want to avoid. In this case you can extend from another controller that implements this either using newer `class` syntax or through the prototype. In this case I think it would be better to use `controllerAs` instead of `$scope.`

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's interesting, but I have some doubts: where should be located this factory? In which file? 1 or 2? And how will you works the "calling" in view? For ex: `<div ng-controller="myCtrlOfJs1">`? And the other controller?

Answer (score 0):

This is a method you can achieve what you are looking for.
I prefer the service method though

Take a look at this :

[use case for $controller service in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866620/use-case-for-controller-service-in-angularjs)

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller

Hope it helps