# How to access a controller from another controller in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use another method from another Controller in an Angularjs Module.
I have two Controller one named: **Booklist** Controller in **bookApp** Module.
and another one named **ShowEachBook**.
In **Booklist** Controller I create **ViewItem()** method which can be accessible from **View_A_book()** method in **ShowEachBook** Controller.

Here is my Controller in BookApp module

```
var bookApp = angular.module('bookApp', []);

bookApp.controller('bookListCtr', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.ViewItems = function ($id) {
        $this->View_A_book($id);// This is example because I want to used View_A_book() method here
    };
 })
```

And here is the **ShowEachBook** Controller

```
bookApp.controller('ShowEachBook', function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.View_A_book = function($id){
       /// get book from server.
  }
})
```

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to grasp. Part of it is due to language I think (if possible, try to review your first paragraph), and part of it is because I don't see how your code can be used to create an [mcve]. Could you check that link and try to both cut some (superfluous) and add some (needed) code?

Comment: View_A_Book method should be created in a service (instead of another controller) and use that service in your controller.

Comment: can you show me some

Comment: Use events to communicate between each other, or in this case maybe use services!

Comment: You must be looking for "broadcast"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866620/use-case-for-controller-service-in-angularjs you can refer this.. you can use $controller.

Answer (score 4):

Create a factory. 
You only have to define it once, and it can be injected and called from any controller. [See this article](http://findnerd.com/account/#url=/list/view/Difference-between-Service-Provider-and-Factory-in-angularJs/4463/).

--

Make a factory `ViewBook`, and add your function to it:
Your factory:

```
angular.module('bookApp')
    .factory('ViewBook', function () {
        return {
            view_a_book: function(id) {
                //do whatever you want to.
                return something 
            },
        };
    });
```

Your controller:

```
var bookApp = angular.module('bookApp', []);

bookApp.controller('bookListCtr', function ($scope, $http, ViewBook) {

    $scope.ViewItems = function ($id) {
        ViewBook.view_a_book($id);
    };
 })
```

You add a reference to the factory with `$scope` and `$http`, and use that to call it. This can be repeated for any controllers you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can write all the methods or functions which is common to your project as a Service. In angular js we can create 2 types of Services

1. Factory
2. Service

In your problem you just write the function 'View_A_Book' as a service and just inject this service to the controller which you want to use the function.

Please refer the below link to get the idea about Service and Factory

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html

Answer (score 0):

To share info betwen controllers use a Service. But for your use case  I sugess use [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) with two  states: `list` and `list.detail` each of them with specific controller. On url of detail map the `id` of the single item `list/book/[id]` and resolve ittrought a API request or list array from parent state.