# How to set default value in an Angular select menu based on data binding instead of index

Tags: angularjs

I would like to set the default item in a select menu based on value rather than by index position. For example, in the sample below, if one of the radio buttons in a form displays "Oranges," and a user selects that radio button, is it possible to make the default selection in the subsequent select menu be Oranges as well? Ideally, I would prefer not to rely on the order of items in the select menu.

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="selectionList.message" value="{{selection.type}}">

<!--Default selection below should be based on value selected above, regardless of order-->

<select ng-model="editProject.project" ng-options="opt as opt.type for opt in editProject.options">
</select>
```

Is there a way to set the default based on value rather than the item's position in the select menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure what you ui is supposed to look like or waht the data structures you are pulling from look like.  But in your ng-change it looks like you are using a value that is foreign to the dataStructure you are trying to manipulate. ie. using a array value to return a nested value in an object. see if the below works for the situation. I also did a [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/idszHgBN1EmxbTw0KWZm?p=preview) that shows an example of it working as well. But here are the main snippets that

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="color" 
       value="{{radioColors.type[1]}}"   
       ng-change="match()">Orange<br>
```

// the select element

```
  <select ng-model="selectValue" 
          ng-options="selectColor as selectColor.type for selectColor in selectColors"></select>
```

// this would go in your controller

```
$scope.match = function () {
    angular.forEach($scope.selectColors, function(value, key) {
      if(angular.equals(value.type, $scope.color)) {
        $scope.selectValue = $scope.selectColors[key]
      }

    });
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you. If one controller is handling the radio buttons and another controller is handling the select menu, could I use that function in a service and share it between two controllers?

Comment: Yep for sure. You would need to use the `$controller` service to 'inject' it into the other controller.  Here is a recent stackoverflow question regarding [injecting another controllers scope.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417162/how-do-i-inject-a-controller-into-another-controller-in-angularjs). Just need to follow the naming configuration pattern.

Comment: thanks again. So in this case, the controller for the radio buttons will be injected into the controller for the select menu?

Comment: I am going to play around with it a little. When I originally looked at the issue. I thought solution should really use directives. But in answering it - i thought to stay true to your current set up would be most clear.

Comment: @Ken here is my [directive solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/PILKqE4xmRXczhuxIiE5?p=preview). It is a much cleaner and on its way to being reusable components. Here is more reading if you are interested in the idea of approaching things from a component approach - which is the future of angular and web dev. [component based directives](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/component-based-angularjs-directives)

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! I also appreciate the link to the blog post on component directives. It's good to have a sense of where Angular is going.

Answer (score 1):

Per [radio input](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D) document, you can add a `ng-change` hook

```
<input type="radio"
   ng-model=""
   value=""
   [name=""]
   [ng-change=""]
   ng-value="">
```

like `ng-change="editProject.project = selection.type"`

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I must be doing something wrong, though, because I'm not able to get it to work.