# Getting checkbox values in angularjs and passing them into another controller

Tags: angularjs

I am transitioning from jquery to angularjs. I am trying to develop a small app in SPA style. Left side is the menu that controls the content on the right side. Left side menu has its own controller. When the user selects a checkbox and clicks on 'Go', the checkbox value should be passed to the controller that controls the right side content. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gz2R6akUqvLllkHDUG4s) is the link to the app. Below are the issues I have.

1)I am stumped on a simple problem of accessing checked values of a checkbox. How do I access values of checked checkboxes. The checboxes are on left side menu, and I am using ng-model to currently access the values as below

index.html

```
<div id="searchOne">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="searchOneCB in main.checkBoxOneData">
          <input type="checkbox" name="firstSearch" id="firstSearch_{{searchOneCB.code}}" ng-model="main.selected[searchOneCB.code]" />
{{searchOneCB.description}}
        </li>
      </ul>

      <button class="btn btn-primary" style="width:80px;margin-right: 10px" ng-click="main.submit()">
          Go
      </button>
</div>
```

MainCtrl.js to access the checkbox value.

```
main.submit = function() {      
  console.log(main.selected);
}
```

The values are now in the form of an array as below

```
[BBBB: true, AAAA: true].
```

Is this the right way to access the values? What is the best way to retrieve only the checked checbox values?

2) Another question is, once I get the list of checked checkboxes values, how can I pass them to the contentCtrl.js that controls the content on right side?

Answer (score 0):

You should inject the controller into the controller you want to use. The answer has already been answered here is the link.

[How do I inject a controller into another controller in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417162/how-do-i-inject-a-controller-into-another-controller-in-angularjs)