# AngularJS: How to filter data in second select tag options based on first select tag's selected id

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing a mobile application where there is a view where there are two select tags first select tag consist of options of teams & in the second select tag there are forms associated with team Ids that user select in first select tag. I want to filter the data of second select tag as per the team Id of first select tag on ng-change event.

For the first select tag i have populated as follows:

```
<select ng-change="showForms(name.id)" ng-model="name" ng-options="f.name for f in devices track by f.id"></select>
```

my second select tag is this:

```
<select ><option ng-repeat="formEach in forms" id="{{formEach.Formid}}">{{formEach.Formname}}</option></select>
```

Here my concern is i dont want to show any forms that are present inside the forms array initially when user is about to select team. When user selects team, the forms with the selected teams id associated should be shown in the second select tag. How the filtering will be occur or is it on same page or through controller. I am familiar with PHP but task is in angular & am new to angularJS.

Thanks in advance for quick response.

Sample data is this:

```
devices = [
{id : X001, name :'Team 1', icon: 'ion-document-text', status : 'Owner', color : 'brown'},
{id : X002, name :'Team 2', icon: 'ion-document-text', status : 'Owner', color : 'yellow'},
{id : X003, name :'Team 3', icon: 'ion-document-text', status : 'Owner', color : 'black'}
];
```

forms data is this:

```
forms= [
{id : AS001, teamid: X001, formname :'Feam 1', icon: 'ion-document-text', status : 'Active'},
{id : AS002, teamid: X001, formname :'Feam 2', icon: 'ion-document-text', status : 'Draft'},
{id : AS003, teamid: X003, formname :'Feam 3', icon: 'ion-document-text', status : 'Draft'}
];
```

controller code is this: (controller logic is not written as am confused of populating the data as am filling the array at the time of navigation to this view)

```
    $scope.showForms = function(teamId){

}
```

Comment: Will you please your controller's code if you've written something ? Else please post your complete object.

Comment: Your second select tag needs to show value only after you select team? is that your requirement?

Comment: Show the JSON or array on which you are iterating. Without the structure it is difficult to suggest any solution

Comment: @Alhuck A yes it should be.

Comment: @Vineet my controller code is not important as when i navigate to that view i am filling all the arrays with values. and these arrays present in parent controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by simply following below trick. I've used the same in one of my project.

```
    <select class="custom-select" ng-model="teamName" data-ng-options="f.id as f.name for f in devices" ng-change="updateTeamObject($index, teamName);">
     <option value="">Select Team</option>
</select>
```

and in your second select, just use.

```
    <select class="custom-select" ng-model="deviceForms" data-ng-options="o.id as o.formname for o in forms | filter:{teamid:teamName}">
      <option value="">Your team data</option>
  </select>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7byw5wh5/)

Comment: The two arrays are in the parent controller, in the controller that i have defined on body tag. I am trying it but couldn't get it workout....

Comment: I got your point. You should read that how to use $controller service in angular. This question will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417162/how-do-i-inject-a-controller-into-another-controller-in-angularjs

Comment: do u have something written in updateTeamObject($index, teamName)

Comment: Yeah. I've written my logics under this function. But your logics may differ from mine one

Comment: Or share your complete code of your scripts then I can help you with it

Comment: listen one little help needed, i want to get the formId when user clicks on button below to pass it to rest. Things is when i extended query like this:o.Formid as o.Formname for o in forms track by o.FormId | filter:{Teamid:teamName} it doesnot populate the forms on selecting team. I want the formId so track by is needed

Comment: try $index without using track by. In angular docs I read "Do not use select as and track by in the same expression. They are not designed to work together. " So use direct $index and see the results

Comment: what does $index do in this case then??

Comment: I've used in one of my script. I use : data-ng-options="product as product.Product.name for product in products" ng-change="updateCartObject($index, productNameOptions.Product.id);". I got $index value in this function. You should try the same

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <select ng-change="showForms(name.id)" ng-model="name" ng-options="f.name for f in devices"></select>
        <select ng-model="selected">
            <option ng-repeat="formEach in forms| filter:{teamid:name.id }" id="{{formEach.id}}">{{formEach.formname}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15890/

**Explanation:** 
Important part is

`ng-repeat="formEach in forms| filter:{teamid:name.id }"`

Note how the filter is used. Specify the property (i.e. teamid in your case) where you want the filter to be applied. Since model `name` stores the selection, you can filter the next select dropdown by using `name.id` . For testing, just select the last option in the first select dropdown in the demo, the next dropdown will have the filtered results.

Comment: The two arrays are in te parent controller no in the controller that i have defined on body tag. does it make something difference in output?? coz i am not getting output

Comment: Make sure that the select tags are within the controllers so that they can access the scope and the respective variables

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by pushing the items you want in the second select tag's array at the time of `ng-change` event of the first tag

In the `ng-change` function, push items into the array like this in the controller,

```
$scope.specifications = [];
angular.forEach($scope.allSpecifications, function(spec) {
  if(spec.id == id) {
    $scope.specifications.push(spec)
  }
});
```

In Html use that array

```
<select ng-change="showSpec(car.id)" ng-init="car = carsList[0]" ng-model="car" ng-options="car.name for car in carsList"></select>
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="primitive in specifications" id="{{primitive.id}}">{{primitive.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I have done one plunker with a sample JSON,

[Working Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/QWXOwSTm36R6GU2BVdVa/preview)

Hope this helps!