# AngularJS: On button click to capture selected tag value

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have code HTMl as follows here i am trying to get the values from select tag:

```
<div class="padding">
        <div class="item item-divider calm-bg" style="color:#ffffff">
        Select Team to Go
        </div>
        <div class="list" >
            <label class="item item-input item-select ">
                <div class="input-label">
                    Select Team
                </div>
                <select ng-model="teamName" ng-options="f.id as f.name for f in devices">
                    <option value="" disabled> Select your team </option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="padding">
<div class="item item-divider calm-bg" style="color:#ffffff">
Select Form to Go
</div>
<div class="list">
     <label class="item item-input item-select">
         <div class="input-label">Select Team</div>

                <div ng-if="(!teamName)">
                    <select>
                        <option value="" disabled> Select your form</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div ng-if="(teamName)">
                    <select ng-model="FormModel" ng-options="f.id as f.formname for f in forms | filter:{teamid:teamName}">
                        <option value="" disabled> Select your form </option>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="padding">
    <button ng-click="showToFillForm(FormModel)" class="button button-calm pull-right">Go!</button>
    </div>
```

I am trying to capture the forms ID using `showToFillForm(Formid)` but it is not capturing what to do to capture select tag value??

Comment: `Formid` does contain any value or not?

Comment: even after selection it does not contain anything. i am consoling it out it is showing undefined.

Comment: could you checked `option` value has rendered on html by inspect element?

Comment: for the option i can see in the debug that value attribute contain the form Id but is not coming in ng-model=FormId

Comment: could you add whole html? because looks like scope issue you had use `ng-repeat` or `ng-if` somewhere

Comment: check update i did just to the question

Comment: Could you please create jsfiddle?

Comment: Could you share your complete code including js? Sharing a piece of code will not help. I doubt whether you have used correct variables in the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Try:

```
<select class="custom-select" ng-model="teamName" data-ng-options="f.id as f.name for f in devices" ng-change="updateTeamObject($index, teamName);">
         <option value="">Select Team</option>
    </select>

 <select class="custom-select" ng-show="teamName" ng-model="deviceForms" data-ng-options="o.id as o.formname for o in forms | filter:{teamid:teamName}">
          <option value="">Your team data</option>
      </select>
```

And in your button

```
<button ng-click="showToFillForm(deviceForms)" class="button button-calm pull-right">
  Go!
</button>
```

As per your previous question's [JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475081/angularjs-how-to-filter-data-in-second-select-tag-options-based-on-first-select/30475809#30475809) data

teamName is previous model of select box

Comment: there is a filter you have not noticed in the code. this one is populating all the forms

Comment: Value attribute ? Will you please elaborate it for me ?

Comment: thing is i need formId of selected option so i am assigning value="{{formEach.Formid}}".

Comment: I've been telling you the same. If you use ng-options then you don't need to use option's ng-repeat. The ng-options directive works like : value as label for element in array. You can see by using f.Formid as f.Formname you don't need to use <option value={{blah}}>

Comment: You should see into your dom that how these directives are showing output over there. Please see your select box's output

Comment: ok i tried your code. This is what it shows in inspect element

Comment: <option value=""> Select your form </option>
<option value="0">Company recruitment</option>  (data changed)

Comment: and on button click it shows me undefined for formModel

Comment: In your case you're not passing the right model's reference in this function showToFillForm(). Please correct it and see the results

Comment: i have edited the question html & tested it if i pass teamName the it shows the id to me but if i pass FormModel it shows empty string i have checked if there is any difference in the code for first select & second select tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78905/discussion-between-vineet-and-shaggie).