# How to inject controller into service using angular js?

Tags: angularjs, inject

I am new to angular and want to know if I can inject controller into service and then that service can be shared into multiple services.

Or help me out to know how can I create a function in service which can be used my multiple controllers?

Comment: Just asking, why on earth would you inject a controller to a service? However you would need to inject [`$controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller) service and instantiate the controller inside the service.

Comment: thanks @PSL. I know i am doing it wrong but i dont have time to refactor the code and use it. so for now the shortest path algorithm :)

Comment: haha. ok. But i'd suggest you to definitely revisit it and refactor. It is a part of a design problem you have... Here is an [answer which suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417162/how-do-i-inject-a-controller-into-another-controller-in-angularjs/25417210#25417210) how to inject.

Comment: well thanks again @PSL. if you can make that an answer i can accept it if you want.