# How to call a function in another controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
unified.controller('YourteamController', function uniYourteamController($scope) {    
    testController.listTeams();
});    

unified.controller('testController', function testController($scope) {
    $scope.listTeams = function() {
        //Listing process
    };    
});
```

I have two controller. I need to call a function(listTeams()) in another controller(testController). How to call this using angularjs

Comment: You are cleanly looking for $rootScope I think ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I inject a controller into another controller in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417162/how-do-i-inject-a-controller-into-another-controller-in-angularjs)

Comment: you mean call a function in controller 1 from controller 2 ?

Comment: yes, I need to call a function in second controller.  @ngLover

Comment: plz refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller

Answer (score 1):

Go the service way. Easier to test, and more in line with 'best practices'.

```
angular.module('sharedService', function () {
  function listTeams () {
    return 'teams!';
  }

  angular.extend(this, {
    listTeams: listTeams
  })
});

angular.module('ctrl1', function ($scope, sharedService) {
  angular.extend($scope, {
    listTeams: sharedService.listTeams
  });
});

angular.module('ctrl2', function ($scope, sharedService) {
  angular.extend($scope, {
    listTeams: sharedService.listTeams
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject first controller as dependency to second controller. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25417210/2034794) is how to do it.

Comment: Whats the difference in your answer and my comment ?

Answer (score 0):

do the following ...

```
  unified.controller('YourteamController', function uniYourteamController($scope) {    
        var testController= $scope.$new();
        $controller('testController',{$scope : testCtrl1ViewModel });
        testController.listTeams();
    });    

    unified.controller('testController', function($scope) {
        $scope.listTeams = function() {
            //Listing process
        };    
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make a service that will return a function that can be used in both controllers having diffrent scope.

========================================

```
unified.controller('YourteamController', function uniYourteamController($scope, $abc) {

$abc.listTeams();
});

unified.controller('testController', function testController($scope, $abc) {
$abc.listTeams();
});

unified.service('abc', function () {


this.listitems = function () {

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
unified.controller('YourteamController', function uniYourteamController($scope) {    
    $scope.$parent.listTeams();
});
```