# AngularJS redirect to the url and call a function

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have a parent controller and some child controllers in my app.
In some cases i need to redirect user to another route url, and call the function after redirect (in url controller).

```html
<div ng-controller="parent">
  <!-- ng-view below -->
  <div ng-controller="url1"></div> <!-- #/url1 -->
  <div ng-controller="url2"></div> <!-- #/url2 -->
 </div>
```

when user still in #/url1 in a particular case i need to redirect to #/url2 and then call a function in url2 controller.

Comment: Its really not a redirection to a page.

Comment: You need to read the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api) because most of us will not write the code for you. Read up on controllers. Also, have a look at [Angular UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use a function in another controller, you can inject that controller into your current controller and then call the function you want using the injected controller.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417162/how-do-i-inject-a-controller-into-another-controller-in-angularjs) out for how to get this done.

This way, you will not be changing the routes as well.

Comment: Thank you, but can i use smth like $location.path('new_url');
 
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (scope, next, current) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('openFunction', note);
    });

Comment: It is not a good practise to use the rootScope of an Angular application. I suggest that injecting the controller is a better way. Or you can move that function into a service and use it by injecting the Service in all your controllers where you will be using the function.