# How to access one module controller inside another module controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have two modules tms2 and tms_sub . I need to access mainCtrl inside mCtrl.
Is this possible.

**Tms**

```
var tms2 = angular.module('tms2', ['tms_sub']);
tms2.controller("mCtrl", ["$scope","$controller", function ($scope,$controller) {
$scope.test = "a1";
$scope.testClick = function () {
   }
}]);
```

**Tms_sub**

```
var tms_sub = angular.module("tms_sub", []);
tms_sub.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
   $scope.test ="a"
   $scope.testClick1 = function() {
       alert($scope.test);
   }
}]);
```

How to call the function testClick1() form mainCtrl of tms_sub module inside function testClick(){} in mctrl of tms2 module.

```
$scope.testClick = function() {
       testClick1()
   }
```

}

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417162/how-do-i-inject-a-controller-into-another-controller-in-angularjs

Comment: Btw follow cheekybastard's answer on the link above instead of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Tip:** Create separate service for common methods and inject into both controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this:

```
var tms2 = angular.module('tms2', ['tms_sub']);
tms2.controller("mCtrl", ["$scope","$controller”,"mainCtrl", function ($scope,$controller, mainCtrl) {
$scope.test = "a1";
$scope.testClick = function () {
   }
}]);
```