# calling a controller from another in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller like this :

```
  .controller('candidatureStartCtrl', function ($scope, $parse, fileUploadCtrl) {

//...code
      fileUploadCtrl.uploadFile($scope.identityDocUpload);
//...code
}
```

in candidatureStartCtrl I'm calling another controller which is `fileUploadCtrl` to use its function `uploadFile()`.

but I get this error in console even though I imported the `fileUploadCtrl` js in the index.html  :

```
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: fileUploadCtrlProvider <- fileUploadCtrl <- CandidatureStartCtrl
```

this is a fiddle with the same concept :

http://jsfiddle.net/7tzXh/143/

How can I solve this ?

Comment: According to the error your fileUploadCtrl is undefined. Make sure you've added proper reference

Comment: @Shreyas as I said I've  imported the `fileUploadCtrl` js in the index.html

Comment: is it in correct order?

Comment: @Shreyas yes it is, I think its due to injection or something like this since I need to use $inject in that case but I dont know how, I'm still learning angularjs

Comment: can you provide fiddle?

Comment: [Injecting controller in another controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417162/how-do-i-inject-a-controller-into-another-controller-in-angularjs). Injecting controller in another controller is not the best way to call a function. Maybe create a service or use some other mechanics like $scope.$broadcast().

Comment: @Shreyas check my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot inject controllers directly without using $controller as mentioned in one of the comments to the question. If you need to share data, you can use `factory` or `service`.

Please find the working fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/7tzXh/144/

Comment: Thanks I actually used that solution before and I wanted to ask if I can to use a controller inside another but since controllers get garbage collected on route changes using a service/factory is the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

`$controller` is used to inject a controller into another. I've created a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fr2ne2cr/) to make it clear.