# Issues updating angular view from another controller

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

In the below, I have a sidenav and a main content section.  I am trying to call the sidenav function from the main controller so the number updtes in the sidenav.  What am I doing wrong here?

This is my view.

```
<div>Teams {{ teams.length }} </div>
```

**This is my sidebar controller:**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('leftNav', function($scope, myFactory) {
  myFactory.getTeams().then(function(res) {
    $scope.teams = res.data;
  })
```

**This is my factory**

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('myFactory', function($http) {

  return {
    getTeams : function() {
        return  $http.get('/teams').then(function(res) {
        return res;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**This is a complete different controller:**

```
 angular.module('myApp').controller('main', function($scope,$http, myFactory) {
     $http.post(...blablabl..).then(function() {
         // What can i call here to update the sidenav above?
    });
});
```

Comment: look at this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417162/how-do-i-inject-a-controller-into-another-controller-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise `$controller` service to call your leftNav controller from your main controller like below

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('main', function($scope,$http, myFactory,$controller) {
     $http.post(...blablabl..).then(function() {
        var leftCTRL= $controller('leftNav', { $scope: $scope.$new() });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like so :

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('leftNav', function($scope, myFactory) {
  myFactory.getTeams().then(function(res) {
    this.teams = res.data;
})



angular.module('myApp').controller('main', function($scope,$http, $controller) {
      var leftNav= $controller('leftNav');

     $http.post(...blablabl..).then(function(res) {
         leftNav.teams = res.data;
    });
});
```

Comment: the data from the post doesnt reflect the teams in my API